# POST XML to a CakePHP REST app - can not read input

Tags: xml, rest, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have been struggling over this for the past week.  I have searched this forum along with others and have not been able to resolver the issue.

Here is the scenario:
I have an iOS app and am sending xML to a CakePHP app.  For simplicity, the following XML is being sent by the iOS app (and also a REST client from my MAC):

```
<log key='aksjdfhalkjsdhf'>
<type number=1 />
<grouping>LOG</grouping>
<message>Test message</message>
</log>
```

You will notice that there is no `<?xml >` definition as the first line in the XML.  If I add the normal `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone=”yes” ?>` as the first line defining the ML but the Cake PHP XML parser throws an error if this line is present.

I tried to add to the following the HTTP headers (but it did not work either):

```
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Ok - now you see what I tried -- lets get into the problem.  In CakePHP, when I have the XML routing setup properly.  The CakePHP app is receiving the POST request.  My problem is that I can not process the POST information.  According to CakePHP docs I should be able to access the variables using the `$this->request->data` array.  I can not access the variables/  I receive the following when issuing a debug on the `$this->request->data` array:

```
array(
    &#039;&lt;log_key&#039; =&gt; &#039;&#039;aksjdfhalkjsdhf&#039;&gt;
&lt;type number=1 /&gt;
&lt;grouping&gt;LOG&lt;/grouping&gt;
&lt;message&gt;Test message&lt;/message&gt;
&lt;/log&gt;


&#039;
)
```

If I look at the raw data coming in I can see the problem:

```
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = file_get_contents('php://input');
debug($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

Results in:

```
&#039;&lt;log key=&#039;aksjdfhalkjsdhf&#039;&gt;
&lt;type number=1 /&gt;
&lt;grouping&gt;LOG&lt;/grouping&gt;
&lt;message&gt;Test message&lt;/message&gt;
&lt;/log&gt;


&#039;
```

So -- from the received data I can see where the problem lies but I can not figure out how to correct it.

My end goal here is to use the POST data sent in by XML and act upon the data.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:
I removed all code and added the lines:

```
$this->request->input('Xml::build', array('return' => 'DOMDocument'));
debug($this->request);
```

The response still had the characters included.  According to the CakePHP documentation this should be an array with the POST parameters.  Here is the debug print (I have included the entire debug so you can see that some HTML was printed properly):

```
<div class="cake-debug-output">
<span><strong>/app/Controller/LogController.php</strong> (line <strong>26</strong>)</span>
<pre class="cake-debug">
object(CakeRequest) {
    params =&gt; array(
        &#039;plugin&#039; =&gt; null,
        &#039;controller&#039; =&gt; &#039;Log&#039;,
        &#039;action&#039; =&gt; &#039;send&#039;,
        &#039;named&#039; =&gt; array(),
        &#039;pass&#039; =&gt; array(),
        &#039;ext&#039; =&gt; &#039;xml&#039;,
        &#039;isAjax&#039; =&gt; false
    )
    data =&gt; array(
        &#039;&lt;log_key&#039; =&gt; &#039;&#039;aksjdfhalkjsdhf&#039;&gt;
&lt;type number=1 /&gt;
&lt;grouping&gt;LOG&lt;/grouping&gt;
&lt;message&gt;Tese message&lt;/message&gt;
&lt;/log&gt;


&#039;
    )
    query =&gt; array()
    url =&gt; &#039;Log/send.xml&#039;
    base =&gt; &#039;/NUVU-LogServer&#039;
    webroot =&gt; &#039;/NUVU-LogServer/&#039;
    here =&gt; &#039;/NUVU-LogServer/Log/send.xml&#039;
    [protected] _detectors =&gt; array(
        &#039;get&#039; =&gt; array(
            &#039;env&#039; =&gt; &#039;REQUEST_METHOD&#039;,
            &#039;value&#039; =&gt; &#039;GET&#039;
        ),
        &#039;post&#039; =&gt; array(
            &#039;env&#039; =&gt; &#039;REQUEST_METHOD&#039;,
            &#039;value&#039; =&gt; &#039;POST&#039;
        ),
        &#039;put&#039; =&gt; array(
            &#039;env&#039; =&gt; &#039;REQUEST_METHOD&#039;,
            &#039;value&#039; =&gt; &#039;PUT&#039;
        ),
        &#039;delete&#039; =&gt; array(
            &#039;env&#039; =&gt; &#039;REQUEST_METHOD&#039;,
            &#039;value&#039; =&gt; &#039;DELETE&#039;
        ),
        &#039;head&#039; =&gt; array(
            &#039;env&#039; =&gt; &#039;REQUEST_METHOD&#039;,
            &#039;value&#039; =&gt; &#039;HEAD&#039;
        ),
        &#039;options&#039; =&gt; array(
            &#039;env&#039; =&gt; &#039;REQUEST_METHOD&#039;,
            &#039;value&#039; =&gt; &#039;OPTIONS&#039;
        ),
        &#039;ssl&#039; =&gt; array(
            &#039;env&#039; =&gt; &#039;HTTPS&#039;,
            &#039;value&#039; =&gt; (int) 1
        ),
        &#039;ajax&#039; =&gt; array(
            &#039;env&#039; =&gt; &#039;HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH&#039;,
            &#039;value&#039; =&gt; &#039;XMLHttpRequest&#039;
        ),
        &#039;flash&#039; =&gt; array(
            &#039;env&#039; =&gt; &#039;HTTP_USER_AGENT&#039;,
            &#039;pattern&#039; =&gt; &#039;/^(Shockwave|Adobe) Flash/&#039;
        ),
        &#039;mobile&#039; =&gt; array(
            &#039;env&#039; =&gt; &#039;HTTP_USER_AGENT&#039;,
            &#039;options&#039; =&gt; array(
                (int) 0 =&gt; &#039;Android&#039;,
                (int) 1 =&gt; &#039;AvantGo&#039;,
                (int) 2 =&gt; &#039;BlackBerry&#039;,
                (int) 3 =&gt; &#039;DoCoMo&#039;,
                (int) 4 =&gt; &#039;Fennec&#039;,
                (int) 5 =&gt; &#039;iPod&#039;,
                (int) 6 =&gt; &#039;iPhone&#039;,
                (int) 7 =&gt; &#039;iPad&#039;,
                (int) 8 =&gt; &#039;J2ME&#039;,
                (int) 9 =&gt; &#039;MIDP&#039;,
                (int) 10 =&gt; &#039;NetFront&#039;,
                (int) 11 =&gt; &#039;Nokia&#039;,
                (int) 12 =&gt; &#039;Opera Mini&#039;,
                (int) 13 =&gt; &#039;Opera Mobi&#039;,
                (int) 14 =&gt; &#039;PalmOS&#039;,
                (int) 15 =&gt; &#039;PalmSource&#039;,
                (int) 16 =&gt; &#039;portalmmm&#039;,
                (int) 17 =&gt; &#039;Plucker&#039;,
                (int) 18 =&gt; &#039;ReqwirelessWeb&#039;,
                (int) 19 =&gt; &#039;SonyEricsson&#039;,
                (int) 20 =&gt; &#039;Symbian&#039;,
                (int) 21 =&gt; &#039;UP\.Browser&#039;,
                (int) 22 =&gt; &#039;webOS&#039;,
                (int) 23 =&gt; &#039;Windows CE&#039;,
                (int) 24 =&gt; &#039;Windows Phone OS&#039;,
                (int) 25 =&gt; &#039;Xiino&#039;
            )
        ),
        &#039;requested&#039; =&gt; array(
            &#039;param&#039; =&gt; &#039;requested&#039;,
            &#039;value&#039; =&gt; (int) 1
        )
    )
    [protected] _input =&gt; &#039;&lt;log key=&#039;aksjdfhalkjsdhf&#039;&gt;
&lt;type number=1 /&gt;
&lt;grouping&gt;LOG&lt;/grouping&gt;
&lt;message&gt;Tese message&lt;/message&gt;
&lt;/log&gt;


&#039;
}
</pre>
</div><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>
                    </title>
    <link href="/NUVU-LogServer/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="icon" /><link href="/NUVU-LogServer/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/NUVU-LogServer/css/cake.generic.css" /></head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h1></h1>
        </div>
        <div id="content">


            <h2>View Problem: Contact IT</h2>
<p class="error">
    <strong>Error: </strong>
    The view for <em>LogController::</em><em>send()</em> was not found.</p>

        </div>
        <div id="footer">
                        <p>
                            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:
The debug while passing the false parameter to prevent encoding the output.  The problem is still the processing of the XML.  The debug output now looks like:

```
########## DEBUG ##########
object(DOMDocument) {

}
###########################
```

Comment: Besides the obvious problem with what you are doing there, could it be that there is something missing in the output that you are showing here, like HTML surrounding it? Also where do you view the output, I would suspect that it's being displayed as text/plain!?

Comment: There is error HTML surrounding the debugging of the array so HTML is shown properly.  the main problem with this is that I can not get the XML to an array from the POST data and act upon that data.

Answer (score 1):

### Invalid XML

First of all that's invalid XML, these curly (`”`) quotes should be either normal single (`'`) or double (`"`) quotes, and the `number` attribute is missing quotes altogether.

### Use debugging techniques appropriate for your environment

Regarding your debugging attempts, try `debug($whatever, false)`, by default the output gets entity encoded, and I would suspect that you are viewing the output as `text/plain` (just guessing here though).

### Mind the content type

That being said, this is not how you access non-`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data, which is (besides file uploads) the only kind of data that makes it into `Request::$data`. Raw input data of any other kind has to be accessed via `Request::input()`. In case the input data makes it into `Request::$data` without you explicitly sending a wrong content type, check whether the software you are using is sending content types by default.

> Applications employing REST often exchange data in non-URL-encoded post bodies. You can read input data in any format using CakeRequest::input(). By providing a decoding function, you can receive the content in a deserialized format:
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> // Get Xml encoded data submitted to a PUT/POST action
> $data = $this->request->input('Xml::build', array('return' => 'domdocument'));
> ```
>
> [...]

Now you can do further processing, like converting the XML document to an array.

See

- **[Cookbook > Request and Response objects > Accessing XML or JSON data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-xml-or-json-data)**
- **[Cookbook > XML > Transforming a XML string in array](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/xml.html#transforming-a-xml-string-in-array)**

TL;DR

So, just send proper XML snippets with a content type of `application/xml`, read it via `Request::input()`, and when you view debug as plain text make sure that it's not entity encoded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use following code to decode the XML

`$this->request->input('Xml::build', array('return' => 'DOMDocument'));`

Check documentation at : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-xml-or-json-data

Comment: I tried the suggestion according to the documentation - this still did not work.

Comment: It is not exact XML Format , hence it did not work. check ndm's answer for issue on your XML. If you got it corrected one can easily use the above code.

Comment: The XML was changed and is correct.  The problem still persists - any other ideas?